# When using createItem method with Location,Location Creates even if it got the same values in all columns

Tags: java, spring, rest, crud

I use h2 in memory db and I don't want to create duplicate locations in my DataBase. Only when I use createItem and input location column id manualy it write it to the same location. Otherwise even if the country city gps coordinates are the same app write it to other location with it's id.

I tried to understand but It's not working

I got these entities.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "item_System_items")
public class Item {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
    private String title;
    private String description;
    private BigDecimal price;
    private Integer stock;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "location_id")
    @Cascade(value={org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.ALL})
    private Location location;
```

And

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "item_System_locations")
public class Location {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;
    private String country;
    private String city;
    private String street;
    private String gpsCoordinates;
```

SETTERS AND GETTERS IS THERE I JUST NOT POST THEM HERE

Controller

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/items")

public class ItemsController {

    @Autowired
    private ItemsService service;


    @PostMapping
    @ResponseStatus(value=HttpStatus.CREATED)
    public int createItem(@RequestBody Item item) {
        return service.createItem(item);
    }
```

Service

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class ItemsService {

    @Autowired
    private ItemJPARepository repository;

    public int createItem(Item item) {
        return repository.save(item).getId();
    }
```

I expect after re-coding app doesn't make new location if the column values are the same.

Thank you people!
If you really help me I would be so happy!

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing in your Entity definitions to tell the ORM about the constraint you want.

You can add [`@UniqueConstraint`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/UniqueConstraint.html) to the `@Table` in your `Location` entity and specify which column(s) must all be in a unique combination (example given in the linked documentation):

```
@Table(
        name="EMPLOYEE", 
        uniqueConstraints=
            @UniqueConstraint(columnNames={"EMP_ID", "EMP_NAME"})
    )
```

This will add a check in the database, if the ORM is managing your database schema, which will throw an exception when violated.

Comment: Besides @ThisIsNoZaku's constraint definition advise you should still handle the exception when a duplicate entry occurs, as far as I know it will be `DataIntegrityViolationException` for spring framework. You can do your check with a simple try catch block within you controller and when you catch the exception you should fetch the existing `Location`, set it to `Item` and re-save it.

Comment: I tried Constraints but it did not work because auto incremented id is different and it doesn't matter that it have the same columns.